# Nodemon not using the --ignore option

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am using Nodemon on an Expressjs project. I have the following in my package.json:

```
"start": "nodemon server.js --ignore 'src/**'"
```

I have tried several variations of the ignore glob, but every time, it still restarts when a file in 'src/' changes.

What do I need to do to get Nodemon to ignore the src directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to add a config nodemon.json with content below:

```
{
  "verbose": true,
  "ignore": ["src/*"]
}
```

"start": "nodemon server.js --config nodemon.json"

Ref: https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: That ignores ALL files, even ones not in the "src/*" directory. I think this may be a bug.

Comment: Oh, it's working fine at my side. I am using node v8.6.0 and npm v5.3.0

Comment: I updated the Nodemon installation, and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

my friend maybe.... just not use ' '.... example:

```
nodemon index.js --ignore src/*
```

that works for me

repeat, not use the '' or ""

Comment: Nice tip. I was using `"` and it didn't work :D