# How to ignore package.json with nodemon

Tags: node.js, json, nodemon

How do I ignore package.json when using nodemon?
(I'm using versiony to increase package.json version).

I tried to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794071/nodemon-not-using-the-ignore-option) but not sure how I can apply that for an extension or file. I tried:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "versiony package.json --patch && node bot.js",
    "nodemonConfig": {
      "ignore": [
        "*.json"
      ]
    }
  }
```

I also tried to use the [guide from nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#ignoring-files) in a start.bat file:

```
@echo off
echo Starting...
:main
REM node bot.js
REM nodemon --delay 2500ms bot.js
nodemon --delay 2500ms --ignore lib/package.json --exec npm start
echo Restarting bot...
goto main
```

That file, I launch and it will start the script "start" in package.json with the delay of 2500ms (before restarting when detecting changes), will ignore package.json (but doesn't)

I expected that when the file is launched, it will start nodemon, ignoring package.json while versiony increases patch version (it does). However, right now, it increases version, but then I guess nodemon detects this new change and restarts, creating an infinite loop of restarting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `nodemon` config `nodemon.json` file and ignore the file like:

```
{
  "ignore": ["*.json"],
}
```

Or set `--ignore` flag like:

```
nodemon --ignore package.json
```

Or in your `package.json`

```
"nodemonConfig": {
  "ignore": ["package.json"]
}
```